# Adding SubTable to a DataGridView

Tags: .net, winforms, datagridview

In .net 1.1 you could have subtables in your DataGrid.  Does anyone have a solution to doing this in a DataGridView .net 3.5?  This is for a WinForms app.

For example:

[image]

If you click the + next to Jane Doe you will get:

[image]

Thanks in advance for any pointers.

Johnie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no good way of achieving this with the `DataGridView`. The closest I've ever seen in real life was a `DataGridView` with grouping done at the SQL level and then custom painting on the summation rows - in the end it worked really nicely but was a lot of work for the desired effect (we were lucky that someone had code that already did 90% of the work).

As I see it your best options are (in no particular order):

1. Classic DataGrid (I've not actually used this but since you say it does grouping...)
2. WPF - the support for this sort of thing in WPF is very good. It still requires some custom development but the framework enables rather that obstructs.
3. Use ReportViewer and make this into a report
4. Have a master-details relation between two datagridviews
5. Buy a third party control

Comment: I think I'm going to have to do two datagrids for the time being.  I'll build a custom control later as time permits.